# resize image to the height of it parent and resize it on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need help with my code

this is my example - http://jsfiddle.net/urK7t/

and full size page - http://dev.fama.net.pl/tides/

concept:
[image]

i would like to have 100% width and 100% height, overflow:hidden DIV with wide image in it witch i can move left and right, this image should resize on window resize, now as u see in my examples is just stretch image height and i would like to resize whole image but i dont want to show whole image it need to be move left and right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles you want for your image are these:

```
#bg-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

In the future, the CSS property you really want is `object-fit`:  http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/control-image-aspect-ratios-css3

Comment: this is it but without width: 100%; i need image to fit just height like this http://jsfiddle.net/urK7t/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can say if you have this image as background to be contain or cover or even to be 100% 100% etc, depends if you want it scaled or just full screen, etc.

Comment: i want to scal it to fit it parent height witch is window height

Comment: -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

The 'cover' keyword indicates that the image should be resized and maintain any intristic aspect ratio.

Comment: i would made the background-size auto 100%; and that should do it, with javascript you can get the window.height and based on it scale the image like saying the window.height is the image y size and then maybe recall the function each time window height changes, dont know, something like that